# Is this right? $ | \nabla f |^k \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n | \partial_i f |^k $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is this right if $ k \geqslant 1$ ? Then why?
$$ | \nabla f |^k \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n | \partial_i f |^k \; $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially just the triangle equality for the so called $p$-norm (in your  case $p=k$) together with the monotonicity of the $k$-th root. 
See this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-norm#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions).

---

Edit:  I was wrong, this now doesn't seem to have to do with $p$-norms.  What was I thinking?
What you want to show is that for a vector $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n$
with all components $\geq 0$ the following holds:
$$(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)^{k/2}\leq x_1^k+\dots+x_n^k$$

Since everything is $\geq 0$, this inequality holds iff it holds for the squares of both sides.
So you want to show 
$$(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)^k\leq(x_1^k+\dots+x_n^k)^2.$$
But this is actually not true:

Suppose $x_1=x_2=1$ and $k=3$.
Then 
$$(x_1^2+x_2^2)^k=2^3=8\not\leq (x_1^k+x_2^k)^2=2^2=4.$$
You get a counterexample to your inequality from this by choosing a function
$f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ with $\partial f/\partial x_1=\partial f/\partial x_2=1$.

Comment: Thank you, I have reduced that $ |\nabla f |^k = (\sum_{i=1}^{n} ( \partial_i f )^2 )^{(k/2)}$. But I don't know what to do next..